# Using Auto Layout in UITableViewCell containing a UICollectionView with asynchronous image load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, ios-autolayout

**TL;DR**: The height calculated by the autolayout engine when displaying the cell containing the collection view is always wrong the first time. Calling `reloadData()` on the table view fixes the issue but also makes the table view to jump and to be unusable. Any idea?

**Explanations**:
I have a table view with many different cells of different heights.

One of these cells is an image gallery that can contain one or more images loaded asynchronously.

The constraints I have are the following:

- if the gallery only contains one image and if this image is oriented in landscape, the height of the gallery should be the height of the image
- else, the gallery has a fixed height.

The problems I face are the following:

- I get the Super Annoying Encapsulated-Height-Layout issue thing when the table view tries to display the gallery cell the first time. This encapsulated height has always the wrong value, even though the height constraint on the collection view has been updated.
- The table view consistently never gets the cell's size right at first try.

  - Even if the image is already retrieved when the cell is displayed, the cell displays poorly and I have to scroll up / down to hide it, then display it again to get the right size... until next time the cell size has to be computed again. See below:
    [image]
- The only way I can get to force the table view to display the cell correctly is when I call reloadData on the table view once the image is loaded the first time... which makes the table view to jump and to be basically unusable.

I'm using Kingfisher to retrieve the images, here's the code:

**UICollectionViewCell Data Source:**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CarouselCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CarouselCollectionViewCell
    guard let collectionView = collectionView as? CarouselCollectionView else { return cell }
    
    if let imagesURLs = data.imagesURLs {
        let url = imagesURLs[indexPath.item]
        
        if let smallURL = url.small {
            KingfisherManager.sharedManager.retrieveImageWithURL(
                smallURL,
                optionsInfo: KingfisherOptionsInfo(),
                progressBlock: nil,
                completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in
                    if let image = image {
                     self.delegate?.imageIsReadyForCellAtIndexPath(image, collectionView: collectionView, screenshotIndex: indexPath.row)
                     cell.imageView.image = image
                    }
            })
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Here is what happens when the **delegate** gets called on the **RooViewController** in `imageIsReadyForCellAtIndexPath(image: UIImage, collectionView: UICollectionView, screenshotIndex: Int)`:

```
func imageIsReadyForCellAtIndexPath(image: UIImage, collectionView: UICollectionView, screenshotIndex: Int) {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView as? CarouselCollectionView else { return }
    guard let collectionViewIndexPath = collectionView.indexPath else { return }
    guard let screenshotsCount = feed?.articles?[collectionViewIndexPath.section].content?[collectionViewIndexPath.row].data?.imagesURLs?.count else { return }
    
    let key = self.cachedSizesIndexPath(collectionViewIndexPath: collectionViewIndexPath, cellIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: screenshotIndex, inSection: 0))
    var sizeToCache: CGSize!
    
    if screenshotsCount == 1 {
        
        // Resize the collectionView to fit a landscape image:
        if image.isOrientedInLandscape {
            sizeToCache = image.scaleToMaxWidthAndMaxHeight(maxWidth: Constants.maxImageWidth, maxHeight: Constants.maxImageHeight)
        } else {
            sizeToCache = image.scaleToHeight(Constants.maxImageHeight)
        }
        
        if collectionViewCellsCachedSizesObject.dict[key] == nil {
            
            let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
            let imageWidth = sizeToCache.width
            let sidesInset = (collectionView.frame.width - imageWidth) / 2
            print("sidesInset: ", sidesInset)
            flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: sidesInset, bottom: 0, right: sidesInset)
            
            collectionViewCellsCachedSizesObject.dict[key] = sizeToCache
            collectionView.heightConstraint.constant = sizeToCache.height
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            collectionView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    } else {
        
        let sizeToCache = image.scaleToHeight(Constants.maxImageHeight)
        
        if collectionViewCellsCachedSizesObject.dict[key] == nil { // && collectionViewCellsCachedSizesObject.dict[key] != sizeToCache {
            collectionViewCellsCachedSizesObject.dict[key] = sizeToCache
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I set my **Collection View**:

```
class CarouselElement: Element {

let collectionView: CarouselCollectionView

func cachedSizesIndexPath(collectionViewIndexPath aCollectionViewIndexPath: NSIndexPath, cellIndexPath aCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> String {
    return "\(aCollectionViewIndexPath), \(aCellIndexPath)"
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: Constants.horizontalPadding, bottom: 0, right: Constants.horizontalPadding)
    layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
    
    collectionView = CarouselCollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    collectionView.registerClass(CarouselCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CarouselCollectionViewCell")
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    collectionView.allowsSelection = true
    collectionView.backgroundColor = Constants.backgroundColor
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    addSubview(collectionView)
    
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "|[collectionView]|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(),
        metrics: nil,
        views: ["collectionView":collectionView]))
    
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|[collectionView]-verticalPadding-|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(),
        metrics: ["verticalPadding":Constants.verticalPadding],
        views: ["collectionView":collectionView]))
    
    collectionView.heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: collectionView,
        attribute: .Height,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 200)
    addConstraint(collectionView.heightConstraint)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setCarouselDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: CarouselDataSourceDelegate?, indexPath: NSIndexPath, cachedHeight: CGFloat?) {
    collectionView.indexPath = indexPath
    if let height = cachedHeight {
        collectionView.heightConstraint.constant = height
    }
    collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointZero
}}
```

And the **Custom Cell** holding it:

```
class CarouselCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let imageView: UIImageView

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    
    imageView = UIImageView.autolayoutView() as! UIImageView
    imageView.image = Constants.placeholderImage
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    addSubview(imageView)
    
    addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "|[imageView]|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(),
            metrics: nil,
            views: ["imageView":imageView]))
    addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|[imageView]|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(),
            metrics: nil,
            views: ["imageView":imageView]))
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    imageView.image = Constants.placeholderImage
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}   }
```

Last but not least, I set the height constraint of the collection view in `tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)`

I tried to to set it also in `cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)`  but it doesn't change anything.

Sorry for the massive code chunk, but this is driving me insane.

Comment: is the `Encapsulated-Height-Layout` value == the rowheight in the storyboard?

Comment: The `Encapsulated-Height-Layout` is equal to 230, which is the default height of the collection view (200) + the vertical spacing (30)

Comment: When That warning appears. it tell's you that it had to break  one of your constraints in order to fix it. probabily, (the height constraint) to fix this warning just make that constraint's priority 999 (if it was 1000).

Comment: @Performat did you find a user friendly fix for this?

Comment: No sorry! It's been a while since this project, and I didn't have to deal with this problem again. Hope you find something!

Answer (score 0):

When That warning appears. it tell's you that it had to break one of your constraints in order to fix it. probabily, (the height constraint) to fix this warning just make that constraint's priority 999 (if it was 1000).

---

For updating the cell after setting the image to it. would you try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                            self.delegate?.imageIsReadyForCellAtIndexPath(image, collectionView: collectionView, screenshotIndex: indexPath.row)
                            cell.imageView.image = image
                            // get the content offset.
                             let offset = self.tableView.contentOffset
                             let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: offset, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
                            // reload the cell
                            tableView.beginUpdates()
                            tableView.endUpdates()
                            // to prevent the jumping you may scroll to the same visible rect back without animation.
                            self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(visibleRect, animated: false)
                        }
```

and remove `tableView.reloadData()`

Please give me a feedback after you try it.

Comment: I set the layout of the cell using three sets of constraints. One horizontal, one vertical (both using vfl) and the last one is a single constraint dedicated to the height of the collection view. The warning says the system recovered by breaking the vertical set of constraints: `Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170292480 V:[Catch_App.CarouselCollectionView:0x150820c00]-(30)-|   (Names: '|':Catch_App.CarouselElement:0x14fd751a0'PictureCarouselIdentifier' )>`

Comment: I tried calling `setNeedsLayout()` and `cell.layoutifNeeded()` on the cell and it didn't help unfortunately.
Regarding the constraints, I did lower the priority of the height constraint of the collection view, but it didn't help either. As hinted by the debug message I think it's because it's not the constraint that is actually generating the warning. But not sure how I should lower the priority of all the vertical constraints... I'll try now setting them individually and lowering their priority.

Comment: would you try reloading the cell itself. Please see my updated answer. and give me the feedback?

Comment: I did try reloading the cell itself and it has the same effect as `reloadData()`. I also tried `tableView.beginUpdates()`, `tableView.endUpdates()`. It makes tableView to jump and to be unusable. I also tried lowering the priority of all the vertical constraints to 999, and then tried to lower the priority of each of them to 999, leaving the others to the default value of 1000 and still, the warning keeps displaying.

Comment: @Performat could you use teamviewer to let me see what's going on so I can give you a better solution?

Comment: Thank you for offering you help, I really do appreciate. Unfortunately, I'm in a professional environment that prevents me from doing so.

Comment: No worries, I find this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift) might be useful for you

Comment: Although this is super whacky i get the expected result which is getting the cell to display properly on first attempt. However, the call to `scrollRectToVisible(_ :, animated: )` makes the inert of the scroll to stop. So whenever the picture is downloaded, the table view stop scrolling 
So I'll have to keep searching for a more user friendly approach.